# unable to edit PATH in Ubuntu 16

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to add google-cloud-sdk in PATH in ubuntu-16.

I try

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

inside .profile

```
export PATH = "$PATH:/$HOME/google-cloud-sdk"
```

but it give me error that

```
bash: export '=' : not a valid identifier
```

I am new to this. Please help.

Comment: Try without spaces PATH=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mwweb correctly pointed out, assignments in BASH (and most other shells) cannot have spaces around the `=` operator. Just remove them:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/google-cloud-sdk"
```

Note that you likely want to remove the leading `/` from the path as well.